# Still on hash codes of mutable objects

Tags: hash, hashtable, hashcode

I know, I know, a lot of questions about hash codes, but I'd like to have an opinion on a couple of solutions for calculating the hash code for mutable objects.

Starting from this assumption ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396%20)):

> In general, for mutable reference types, you should override GetHashCode only if:
>
> - You can compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable; or
> - You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code.
>
> Otherwise, you might think that the mutable object is lost in the hash table.

Which is the best option when I need to store mutable object into a hash table?

**SOLUTION 1**

Ignore the problem. Calculate if with one of the available algorithms (here and example for a geo coordinate in C#):

```
public override Int32 GetHashCode() {
    Int32 n1 = 99999997;
    Int32 hash_lat = this.Latitude.GetHashCode() % n1;
    Int32 hash_lng = this.Longitude.GetHashCode();
    _final_hashcode = (((hash_lat << 5) + hash_lat) ^ hash_lng);
    return _final_hashcode.Value;
}
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Calculate it the first time on the mutable values and store it for next times:

```
private Int32? _final_hashcode = null;
public override Int32 GetHashCode() {
    // hash code must not change when lat and lng does change
    if (_final_hashcode == null) {
        Int32 n1 = 99999997;
        Int32 hash_lat = this.Latitude.GetHashCode() % n1;
        Int32 hash_lng = this.Longitude.GetHashCode();
        _final_hashcode = (((hash_lat << 5) + hash_lat) ^ hash_lng);
    }
    return _final_hashcode.Value;
}
```

**SOLUTION 3**

Add a private immutable key for the object to be used only for the hash code. In this way when the mutable fields change, the hash code does not change.

Here an example using a random generated private GUID that is not required for the class and used only for the hash code:

```
public class GeoPosition {

    private const Guid _guidForHash = Guid.NewGuid(); // init during contruction

    public override Int32 GetHashCode() {
        return _guidForHash.GetHashCode();
    }

    // mutable properties here and other stuff
    // ...
}
```

Which is your opinion?

Comment: I don't know all of the relevant criteria in judging between the solutions -- but the third one strikes me as cleanest even if it has a bit of overhead.

Comment: It sounds like a XY-problem to me. All of your solutions have problems. For solution 1 it is obvious (you wrote yourself). For solution 2 and 3, two objects that have the same data could result in different hash codes, depending on when the hash code was computed first. So: you need to better describe what your _real_ problem is.

Comment: @ThomasMueller You're right. Anyhow, where did you get the info that two objects having the same data and different hash codes is an issue? Is is a requirement of the hash code calculation, or what?

Comment: @ThomasMueller  I have not a specific problem. It is a general question I have every time I create classes that I know I will use in hash set and/or a sortable list

Comment: In this case... I recommend not to use mutable objects as keys for maps. All your solutions will prevent finding your object in a hash table, except if you pass the exact same object as the key.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy:

- **SOLUTION 2**: If you have objects o1 and o2 and they have different field values they have different hash codes. If you then change the fields of those objects so that they are equal to each other they still won't have the same hash code. It breaks the constraint: `o1 == o2 implies hash(o1) == hash(o2)`. Unworkable solution.
- **SOLUTION 3**: Same problem as 2.
- **SOLUTION 1**: A correct hash function, but requires recalculating the hash code every time.

So **SOLUTION 1** it is. If you need to optimize it (remember that premature optimization is the root of all evil), you can cache the hash code and have it updated after every attribute write:

```
private Int32 UpdateHashCode() {
        Int32 n1 = 99999997;
        Int32 hash_lat = this.Latitude.GetHashCode() % n1;
        Int32 hash_lng = this.Longitude.GetHashCode();
        cached_hashcode = (((hash_lat << 5) + hash_lat) ^ hash_lng);
}
private Int32 cached_hashcode = null;
public override Int32 GetHashCode() {
    if (cached_hashcode == null) {
        UpdateHashCode();
    }
    return cached_hashcode.Value;
}
private string latitude;
public string Latitude {
    set {
        latitude = value;
        UpdateHashCode();
    }
}
private string longitude;
public string Longitude {
    set {
        longitude = value;
        UpdateHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx for your solution, but how you solve the fact that "the hash code of a mutable object must not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code"?